# using a global variable - can jQuery alert an "id" when button is hovered over?

Tags: jquery, html

using a GLOBAL variable - is there a way that you can get jQuery to alert an **id** when a button is hovered over?

I can get it to alert when the variable is set within the function. But cannot get it to alert when using as a Global variable, hope this makes sense :-)

I am new to coding so a snippet of code and an explanation would be great to helping me understand where I have gone wrong.

```
<body>


  </div>

  <div id="buttonBar">

     <button class="button active" id="html">HTML</button>

     <button class="button" id="css">CSS</button>  

     <button class="button" id="javascript">JavaScript</button>  

     <button class="button active" id="output">Output</button> 

  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

     var panelID = $(this).attr("id");

     $(".button").hover().alert(panelID);


</script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code is wrong:

```
var panelID = $(this).attr("id");
```

You are referring `this` that points to document itself, because there is no context set for `this`.

---

```
$(".button").hover().alert(panelID);
```

Your `hover` will happen after you already set panelID to `undefined`. Also jQuery does not have method `.alert()` and it should be as callback of `hover()` because now it does nothing.

---

Put alert to hover callback function and only then get ID of element that you hovered:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.button').mouseenter(function () {
    // "this" now referrs to button you hovered
    var panelID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(panelID);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonBar">

     <button class="button active" id="html">HTML</button>

     <button class="button" id="css">CSS</button>  

     <button class="button" id="javascript">JavaScript</button>  

     <button class="button active" id="output">Output</button> 

  </div>
```

---

Please note that I am using [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).
hover function accepts 1~2 parameters for in/out handler, while mouseenter fires only when you move mouse over element.

Comment: This works perfect but is there a way that I can create a global variable that alerts the ID of any element I hover over.  i.e. if I am hovering over a button it will give me the ID or if I am hovering over a textarea it will give me the ID.  in essence I am looking to create a variable that I can apply to several elements and am therefore trying to avoid having to create a variable within a function for each element to achieve this (sorry if i`m not making much sense).

Comment: @Coder Your request is not valid, because ID value of global variable will not be changed. If you wish to alert current element ID, then you have to get this property when you do hover and not before that

Comment: Thank you, so my understanding is that you can not call up the ID until after you have hovered over the element and therefore setting a global variable will not work as the variable will take place before the hover?

Answer (score 0):

no, you don't need it, "this" is not what you expect in your snippet.

I suppose that you want to know what button was hovered over?

then:

```
 $(".button").on('mouseover', function(e) { alert(e.target.id);});
```

Comment: Explain why *yes*

Comment: `e.target` can be different than event bound element. Not sure what OP is expecting here. BTW, there is no more event `hover` in jQuery  http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword **within** the hover event handler to get hovered button element:

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: This would be fired twice, on mouseenter and mouseleave. I don't think OP expects it

Comment: @A.Wolff , you are right. But Justinas' answer removes all questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        alert(this.id);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(‘button’).mouseenter(function(e){
           alert(e.target.id);
       });   
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Yes.. will do that